# Why can this C code run correctly?

Tags: c

The C code likes this:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <unistd.h> 
 #define DIM(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])) 
 struct obj
 {
     int a[1];
 };
 int main()
 {
     struct obj *p = NULL;
     printf("%d\n",DIM(p->a));
     return 0;
 }
```

This object pointer `p` is `NULL`, so, i think this `p->a` is illegal.
But i have tested this code in Ubuntu14.04, it can execute correctly. So, I want to know why...

---

Note: the original code had `int a[0]` above but I've changed that to `int a[1]` since everyone seems to be hung up on that rather than the *actual* question, which is:

***Is the expression `sizeof(p->a)` valid when `p` is equal to `NULL`?***

Comment: Not what's happening here, but don't assume that "illegal" things (undefined behaviour) don't appear to work. They can, in fact, appear to work for a very long time before something as simple as a compiler version upgrade breaks them.

Comment: The title said C, the first sentence said C, the headers are C headers, you've used `printf` rather than `cout`, there's not even a little bit of C++ code in the question, so I'm at a total loss as to why it was tagged C *and* C++ :-) Still, it's a good question.

Comment: Chris Beck is absolutely correct: your `#define DIM()` macro is *compile time*.  It's only the *type* that matters here: not the actual run-time values.

Comment: Based on the code here `p->a` does not appear to be an illegal operation, whether or not the `printf(...)` statement will produce something meaningful is a different question.   Based on the code there is nothing that is strictly speaking "illegal" going on, can you give a more specific example of where this behavior might create a problem?

Comment: @paulsm4, the macro itself is a compile time operation but I'm pretty certain there's nothing in the standard saying the sizeof *has* to be so. In fact, for VLAs, it cannot be. For efficiency, non-VLAs are probably best done at compile time but language lawyers need to draw the distinction between "must be so" and "probably is so" (or even "almost certainly is so").

Comment: @paxdiablo it's 2015, isn't it about time to stop treating C++ as a superset of C?

Comment: @Matt, I thought that's what I was doing, by removing the C++ tag. Maybe I should have been clearer.

Comment: @paxdiablo all of this code is valid C++ except for `int a[0];` which is invalid in both languages. OP could be using a C++ compiler, we don't know

Comment: @paxdiablo: i didn't know about the behavior of sizeof with VLAs -- I think my answer is correct in C++ anyways. (Not that it's relevant to the question I'm just trying to keep it straight for my benefit.) I'm looking in section 5.3.3 "Sizeof", in clause 1 it says that when applied to an expression, the operand is unevaluated. (full stop)

Comment: @ChrisBeck yes, C++ doesn't have VLAs. paxdiablo is right that there is no formal distinction between "compile time" and "run time"

Comment: `int a[0];` is *not* illegal in C (as in the C standard), it's invalid in a strictly conforming program, just *one* of the program types described in the standard.

Comment: @paxdiablo my understanding is that "illegal" or "invalid" is common terminology for a program with constraint violations or undefined behaviour . The C11 standard has a term "correct program" but does not define that very clearly.

Comment: @Matt, then it looks like it's just a difference in terminology. I read "illegal" as something you're not actually *allowed* to do (would have to be rejected by a compiler). On the correct/conforming/strictly-conforming stuff, yes, I remember that being very difficult to sort out. We did it eventually but it gave lots of headaches along the way :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo is there another SO thread on the topic?  I don't see anywhere in C11 where it says that programs with constraint violations may or may not be rejected by a conforming implementation. The only cases are that "correct program" (whatever that means) must be translated, and `#error` must be rejected.

Comment: @Matt, I think that's covered by the last bit of section 4, point 6: `A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any strictly conforming program.`. The idea, I believe, is to ensure *every* conforming implementation will correctly run a strictly conforming program, but *may* also run non-conforming programs as well. Perhaps this is worthy of another question rather than continuing here?

Comment: Is the fact that zero-size array is illegal in C really so poorly known?

Comment: @this: OMG, that's hilarious :-) This question actually has nothing to do with zero length arrays, though I'll admit it may seem that way given the sidetracking happening in the comments. The question is simply to do with whether `sizeof(p->a)` is valid when `p == NULL`. In fact, given the confusion being caused, I think I'll go edit that zero out.

Answer (score 35):

Because `sizeof` is a compile time construction, it does not depend on evaluating the input. `sizeof(p->a)` gets evaluated based on the declared type of the member `p::a` solely, and becomes a constant in the executable. So the fact that p points to null makes no difference.

The runtime value of `p` plays absolutely no role in the expression `sizeof(p->a)`.

In C and C++, `sizeof` is an *operator* and not a function. It can be applied to either a *type-id* or an *expression*. Except in the case that of an expression and the expression is a variable-length array (new in C99) (as pointed out by paxdiablo), the expression is an *unevaluated operand* and the result is the same as if you had taken `sizeof` against the *type* of that expression instead. (C.f. C11 references due to paxdiablo below, C++14 working draft 5.3.3.1)

Comment: Also worth pointing out `sizeof` is an operator, not a function. Might relieve some confusion along the way.

Comment: Arrays of length zero are illegal in Standard C, but allowed in GNU C (which is emphatically not the same as Standard C).  Flexible array members don't count — the dimension there is not 0 so much as unspecified.

Comment: That is `sizeof(p)` and `sizeof((struct obj))` have no difference? Whatever the value of p is.

Comment: `sizeof` is compile-time unless you're taking the size of a VLA type.

Comment: @Yang.fr well, `sizeof(*p)` and `sizeof(obj)` have no difference. `sizeof(p)` is the same as `sizeof(obj*)`

Answer (score 16):

First up, if you want truly portable code, you shouldn't be attempting to create an array of size zero<sup>1</sup>, as you did in your original question, now fixed. But, since it's not really relevant to your question of whether `sizeof(p->a)` is valid when `p == NULL`, we can ignore it for now.

From C11 section `6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators` (my bold):

> 2/ The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The ***size is determined from the type*** of the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, ***the operand is not evaluated*** and the result is an integer constant.

Therefore no evaluation of the operand is done unless it's a variable length array (which your example is not). Only the type itself is used to figure out the size.

---

<sup>1</sup> For the language lawyers out there, C11 states in `6.7.6.2 Array declarators` (my bold):

> 1/ In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword `static`, the `[` and `]` may delimit an expression or `*`. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, ***it shall have a value greater than zero.***

However, since that's in the *constraints* section (where `shall` and `shall not` do not involve undefined behaviour), it simply means the program itself is not strictly conforming. It's still covered by the standard itself.

Comment: But arrays of length zero are illegal in Standard C, though GCC allows them as an extension.   Flexible array members don't count — the dimension there is not 0 so much as unspecified.

Comment: @Jonathan, I'm not sure that's relevant to the question itself, as you could fix it by simply turning that `0` into a `1` and the question would still be valid, since it's about whether or not `sizeof(p->a)` is illegal when `p` is `NULL`. Still, I'll include it in the answer for completeness.

Comment: The structure declaration is illegal — whether it is used for anything or not.  A program containing that struct type is not standard-conforming C.

Comment: @Jonathan, I have to disagree there, the standard allows for non-conformance. It specifically mentions conforming, strictly conforming, and non-conforming programs and implementations, and allows implementation to be conforming provided their extensions don't change the behaviour of strictly conforming programs. So, while the statement that the code is not a strictly conforming one is correct, that *doesn't* mean it's illegal C as per the standard.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain/pedant to all and sundry, it's just we had to cover all this ground when I was working on standards-compliance for a previous employer's compilers. I'm *still* suffering from those encounters :-)

Comment: In C program, how can we define a variable length array? For example, `int *p = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int))` is a variable length array? If it is a variable length array, the value of `sizeof(p)` will be decided at runtime?

Comment: @Yang.fr `int x = rand() % 10 + 1; int p[x];`

Comment: ISO 9899:2011 §5.1.1.3 **Diagnostics** _A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in
an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit
contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly
specified as undefined or implementation-defined._  And in §6.7.6.2 **Array declarators** ¶1 (under 'Constraints'): _If the expression is a constant expression, it shall
have a value greater than zero._  The code shown in the question requires a diagnostic from a conforming compiler.

Comment: Clearly, if the compiler is not conforming to the C standard, then the C standard doesn't impose any requirement on it, but it is hard to say much about the compiler or the language it accepts without a specification of the alternative language.  However, there's not much point in further discussion; this answer recognizes that the 0-size array is on tenuous ground, and we can leave it at that.

Comment: @Jonathan, I have no problem with that, I think you're spot on. I'd just like to add that a diagnostic doesn't mean the code is illegal - a warning is a diagnostic, after all (I think it is, anyway). But, given the amount of time we've all spent on what's really a peripheral issue to the actual question, maybe we should ask another question on the language lawyer aspects, rather than further cluttering up the comments here and risk having hidden what is, after all, a deep discussion.

Answer (score 6):

This code contains a constraint violation in ISO C because of:

```
struct obj
{
    int a[0];
};
```

Zero-sized arrays are not permitted anywhere. Therefore the C standard does not define the behaviour of this program (although [there seems to be some debate](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c/WNVXRSCqrGU) about that).

The code can only "run correctly" if your compiler implements a non-standard extension to allow zero-sized arrays.

Extensions must be documented (C11 4/8), so hopefully your compiler's documentation defines its behaviour for `struct obj` (a zero-sized struct?) and the value of `sizeof p->a`, and whether or not `sizeof` evaluates its operand when the operand denotes a zero-sized array.

Comment: Note that GCC is a compiler that implements a non-standard extension to allow zero-sized arrays.

Comment: Perhaps (after reading comments to other questions), you may want to tone down the "illegal" bit. It's no so much illegal as it is invalid in a strictly conforming program. Implementations are specifically allowed to provide extensions provided they don't change the behaviour of strictly conforming programs. Hence they're covered by ISO C as well. And the bit restricting zero-sized array in in a constraints section which has nothing to do with UB.

Comment: @paxdiablo have changed wording.  In C++ constraint violations are explicitly UB; but it looks like the C standard writers have chosen to be vague instead ...

Comment: See my comments under @paxdiablo's answer.  The code in the question requires a diagnostic from a conforming compiler.  If the compiler isn't conforming to the standard, then the standard has no affect on the compiler and it can do what the hell it pleases.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, but what can/must the compiler do after giving the diagnostic?

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof()` doesn't care a thing about the content of anything, it merely looks at the resulting type of the expression.

Since `C99` and `variable length arrays`, it is computed at run time when a variable length array is part of the expression in the `sizeof` operand.Otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an `integer constant`

`Zero-size array` declarations within `structs`  was never permitted by any `C standard`, but some older compilers allowed it before it became standard for compilers to allow `incomplete array declarations with empty brackets(flexible array members)`.